# How do I type nested objects with typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I was trying to receive the autocompletion of a nested object from a function but I just can't make it work.

**Example:**

I have the tree object above.

```
const tree = {
  branch1: {
    leaf1: {
      bug1: "ant",
    },
  },
  branch2: {
    leaf2: {
      bug2: "ladybug",
    },
  },
};
```

and the above function with some types:

```
type TreeKeys = keyof typeof tree;
type LeafKeys = keyof typeof tree[TreeKeys];

const useTree = (branchName: TreeKeys, bugName: LeafKeys) => {
  return tree[branchName][bugName];
};
```

Is it possible to get the autocomplete for this case?

```
const { bug2 } = useTree("branch2","leaf2");
```

I expected `branch2`, `leaf2` and `bug2` to be autocompleted, but only `branch2` does.

Answer (score 1):

Make both arguments generic, so that TypeScript can determine the possible output types depending on the argument passed in.

```
const tree = {
  branch1: {
    leaf1: {
      bug1: "ant",
    },
  },
  branch2: {
    leaf2: {
      bug2: "ladybug",
    },
  },
};
type Tree = typeof tree;
type TreeKeys = keyof Tree;
const useTree = <T extends TreeKeys, U extends keyof Tree[T]>(branchName: T, bugName: U) => {
  return tree[branchName][bugName];
};
const { bug2} = useTree("branch2","leaf2" as const);
```